# json gets deformed during return from PHP to Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

My Ajax call is:

```
var fetchBooks = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "backend.php"
    data: data
});
fetchBooks.done(function(data){
    alert("Good Ajax!");
});
fetchBooks.fail(function(){
    alert("Bad Ajax");
});
```

My PHP is:

```
[some code to connect to the DB]
$sql = "SELECT book, author FROM books";
$stmt =  $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt -> execute();
$result = $stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
header('Content-Type: application/json', true);
echo json_encode($result);
```

My `json_encode($result)` looks like: `[{"Author":"Jules Verne","Title":"The Lottery Ticket"},{"Author":"Victor Hugo","Title":"Odes"}];`

The problem is, the Ajax fails... And what I notice is this json, when it comes back to Ajax looks like: `[{\"Author\":\"Jules Verne\",\"Title\":\"The Lottery Ticket\"},{\"Author\":\"Victor Hugo\",\"Title\":\"Odes\"}]`

Anyone can explain what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it will get deformed because when you encode your data it will return into a string.

Comment: Is your query result a stdClass obj  or an array?

Comment: It is an array. It only looks like [{"Author":"Jules Verne","Title":"The Lottery Ticket"},{"Author":"Victor Hugo","Title":"Odes"}] if I put a watch variable on the entire thing: json_encode($result).

Comment: You can pass this parameter to json_encode , JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES like this 

json_encode($result,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

Comment: You can also use `json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`